# How do I subtract the amount of rows in one relation from the number of rows in another relation?

Tags: sql, sqlite, math, count

The question here is quite self-explanatory. I want to know if there is a way to count up the amount of rows in two SQL relations and perform really any arithmetic on the resulting numbers.

```
select count(*) from tbl_1 - count(*) from tbl_2
```

It is effectively what I am trying to do here, but obviously this does not work.

I am working with a table of students and another of friendships between students as such

```
Student
SID| name | grade
---|------|------
001|John  |   6  
002|David |   9
003|Diane |   6
004|Dana  |   8
005|David |   7

Friend
SID1|SID2
----|----
001 | 002
001 | 003
004 | 005
```

My expected result from subtracting the count of rows from the Student table and the count of rows from the Friend table would be 2 (5 rows in Student - 3 rows in Friend)

largely in the same way that you can query

```
select 5-3
```

and receive

```
5-3|
---|
 2 |
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get it. How do you get the 2? You check on SID1 or SID2 in friend table? Can you make your expected result in a table form as well?

Comment: I'm not trying to compare aspects of the table, just take the number of rows in each and subtract the values.

Comment: meaning to say you are trying to get the total rows in the first table - total rows in second table?

Comment: simply put, yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can do in this way

```
SELECT COUNT(*) - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Friend) AS difference FROM Student
```

Check out [fiddle here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hdHg58fWRbufH1w8dgjKgu/2)